# Component not displaying, not sure why

Tags: reactjs

the condition below will display the result of postItems function but not the NoPostsExists Component when the length is 0.

```
The condition:   {posts.length == null ? <NoPostsExists /> : this.postItems()}
```

The post that isnt displaying:

```
NoPostsExists = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return (
        <div className="container"> No posts.. No posts.. No posts.. No posts.. No posts.
    No posts.. No posts.. No posts.. No posts.. No posts.
    No posts.. No posts.. No posts.. No posts.. No posts.
. </div>
  ) 
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array#length` is a number. Comparing `posts.length` to `null` makes no sense. You want to compare it to zero (`0`).

Additionally I'd recommend always using triple equals (`===`) and not double equals (`==`) for comparisons. Double equals has some surprising edge cases which can trip you up.

Comment: Thats It! ..dont know how i missed that. Thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

@David gave you the correct solution.

Another better way is don't compare at all! And rewrite the ternary operator as :

```
posts.length ? <NoPostsExists /> : this.postItems()
```

because 0 is considered as false in boolean, so it would work just fine.

Comment: Good thing to know!   cheeers